# How can I redirect my users to a specific page according to a value when clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, redirect, button

So i'd like to redirect the user to another page when the button is clicked according to a certain value (for example, if the value is "8", i would like the user to be redirected to the "8.html" page).

I'm using a select to make the user able to choose between the differents values (timezones here)

I tried using if instructions without any success. If anyone knows how to do so it'd help me a lot. Thanks.

Here's what i got so far :

```js
function redirectTZ() {
  var tz = value

  document.write(tz);

  if (tz == -4);
  window.location.assign("gmt+1.html");
  if (tz == -3);
  window.location.href = "gmt-3.html";
  if (tz == 0);
  window.location.href = "gmt+0.html";
  if (tz == 1);
  window.location.href = "gmt+1.html";
  if (tz == 3);
  window.location.href = "gmt+3.html";
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option timeZoneId="11" gmtAdjustment="GMT-06:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-4">(GMT-04:00) Washington</option>
  <option timeZoneId="23" gmtAdjustment="GMT-03:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-3">(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires</option>
  <option timeZoneId="30" gmtAdjustment="GMT+00:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="0">(GMT+00:00) Lisbon, London</option>
  <option timeZoneId="30" gmtAdjustment="GMT+00:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="0">(GMT+00:00) Lisbon, London</option>
  <option timeZoneId="33" gmtAdjustment="GMT+01:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="1">(GMT+01:00) Brussel, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
  <option timeZoneId="46" gmtAdjustment="GMT+03:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="3">(GMT+03:00) Moscou, St. Petersburg</option>
</select>

<button onclick="redirectTZ()">Valider</button>
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What's not working? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and revise to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. I would suggest setting an id to your select, get the selected value and use that value to create the url.

**HTML**

```
<select id="select_id">
  <option timeZoneId="11" gmtAdjustment="GMT-06:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="-4">(GMT-04:00) Washington</option>
  <option timeZoneId="23" gmtAdjustment="GMT-03:00" useDaylightTime="0" value="-3">(GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires</option>
  <option timeZoneId="30" gmtAdjustment="GMT+00:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="+0">(GMT+00:00) Lisbon, London</option>
  <option timeZoneId="30" gmtAdjustment="GMT+00:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="+0">(GMT+00:00) Lisbon, London</option>
  <option timeZoneId="33" gmtAdjustment="GMT+01:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="+1">(GMT+01:00) Brussel, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris</option>
  <option timeZoneId="46" gmtAdjustment="GMT+03:00" useDaylightTime="1" value="+3">(GMT+03:00) Moscou, St. Petersburg</option>
</select>

<button onclick="redirectTZ()">Valider</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function redirectTZ() {
  // Get the selected value
  var tz = document.getElementById("select_id").value;
  // Redirect user
  window.location.assign("gmt"+tz+".html");
}
```

Comment: It's so simple and yet i didn't even thought of it. Tysm it helped greatly for my school project haha.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the selected value from the dropdown. Please try this,

```
<script>
function redirectTZ() {
var tz = document.querySelector("select").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

for me I will create a form and I will use the submission of this form to retrieve the value of an option through the name attribute of the select

**html**

```
<form id="form">
  <select name="timezone">
    <option
    timeZoneId="11"
    gmtAdjustment="GMT-06:00"
    useDaylightTime="1"
    value="-4"
    >
        (GMT-04:00) Washington
    </option>
    <option
    timeZoneId="23"
    gmtAdjustment="GMT-03:00"
    useDaylightTime="0"
    value="-3"
    >
        (GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires
    </option>
    <option
    timeZoneId="30"
    gmtAdjustment="GMT+00:00"
    useDaylightTime="1"
    value="0"
    >
        (GMT+00:00) Lisbon, London
    </option>
    <option
    timeZoneId="30"
    gmtAdjustment="GMT+00:00"
    useDaylightTime="1"
    value="0"
    >
        (GMT+00:00) Lisbon, London
    </option>
    <option
    timeZoneId="33"
    gmtAdjustment="GMT+01:00"
    useDaylightTime="1"
    value="1"
    >
        (GMT+01:00) Brussel, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris
    </option>
    <option
    timeZoneId="46"
    gmtAdjustment="GMT+03:00"
    useDaylightTime="1"
    value="3"
    >
        (GMT+03:00) Moscou, St. Petersburg
    </option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit">Valider</button>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.onsubmit = submit;

function submit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 const tz = parseInt(event.target.timezone.value);

 console.log(tz);

 switch (tz) {
  case -4:
    return (window.location.href = "gmt+1.html");
  case -3:
    return (window.location.href = "gmt-3.html");
  case 0:
    return (window.location.href = "gmt+0.html");
  case 1:
    return (window.location.href = "gmt+1.html");
  case 3:
    return (window.location.href = "gmt+3.html");

  default:
    break;
  }
}
```